# Drag and drop image to the canvas (vue.js)

Tags: vuejs2, drag-and-drop

I try to create a web app with a concept that same as Canva for my uni course project. I'm a newbie of vue.js and still not familiar with it. May I know how can I drag and drop the image into the canvas? I google it for a long time but still can't find the solution. Please help me if you have any solutions or ideas.

here is my interface, I want to drag and drop the image into the canvas.
[Create illustration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmPIq.png)

**here is my code:**

```
<template>


 <div class="flex-column">
        <!-- top navigation bar -->
        <div class="header" style="background-color: #264D59; padding: 0 25px">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md col-12">
                <h3 class="col-2 header-title m-0 p-0">Illus Dream</h3>
                <div class="col-10 collapse navbar-collapse m-0 p-0">
                    <div class="navbar-nav pt-1 w-100" style="height:55px; font-size:16px;">
                        <div class="nav-item nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                            <i class="align-self-center fas fa-undo-alt fa-lg"></i>
                            <span>Undo</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                            <i class="align-self-center fas fa-redo-alt fa-lg"></i>
                            <span>Redo</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                            <i class="align-self-center fas fa-eraser fa-lg"></i>
                            <span>Clear All</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                            <input class="title " type="text" placeholder="Untitled">
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item nav-link d-flex flex-column ml-auto pr-0">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn text3 border-right-0 pt-1" style="font-size:16px">Save
                                    <i class="far fa-save fa-lg pl-2" style="line-height: 1"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split text" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-0 text-center">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text2" href="#">PNG <i class="fas fa-download fa-lg pl-2"></i></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text2" href="#">SVG <i class="fas fa-download fa-lg pl-2"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
      
     <!-- side navigation bar -->
            <div class="container mx-0" style="width:100%; max-width: 100vw">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="sidenav col-1 px-0">
                        <div class="flex-column menu" id="menu">
                            <button @click="backHome()" style="padding: 6px 19px"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>Home</button>                           
                            <button v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id" :class="{activeBtn:drawer.id == selected}" @click.prevent="activated(drawer.id)" >
                                <span v-html="drawer.icon"></span>{{drawer.text}}
                            </button>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div v-if="!active" class="sub-sidenav col-3" >
                        <div class="flex-column">
                             <div class="form-group has-search">
                                <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control text" placeholder="Search...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row p-3">
                                <div v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id">
                                    <div v-if="drawer.id === selected">
                                        <div class="column" v-for="item in drawer.items" :key="item.id">
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 7rem;height: 7rem">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <span class="center" v-html="item.svg" draggable="true" @dragstart="startDrag($event, item)"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space col-8">
                        <div  @dragover.prevent @dragleave.prevent @drop="onDrop($event, 1)" class="workspace"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {


    data() {
        return{
            selected: undefined,
            active: 'false',

            drawers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Character",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43.808" height="145.733" viewBox="0 0 43.808 145.733">' +
                                ' <g id="Group_9" data-name="Group 9" transform="translate(-1183.765 -369.402)">' +
                                        '<path id="Path_84" data-name="Path 84" d="M568.051,437.983a3.832,3.832,0,0,0,2.548-2.014,3.887,3.887,0,0,0,.1-3.263l14.106-32.131-8.069-2.049-11.328,32.228a3.892,3.892,0,0,0-1.865,4.8,3.841,3.841,0,0,0,4.5,2.432Z" transform="translate(626.349 12.29)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_85" data-name="Path 85" d="M596.337,403.246l-7.848-3.7a1.737,1.737,0,0,1-.7-2.522l4.77-7.262a4.748,4.748,0,0,1,6.342-2.3,4.821,4.821,0,0,1,2.277,6.394l-2.466,8.318a1.725,1.725,0,0,1-.942,1.083A1.7,1.7,0,0,1,596.337,403.246Z" transform="translate(610.773 19.676)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_86" data-name="Path 86" d="M335.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(875.771 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_87" data-name="Path 87" d="M601.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.481-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(610.56 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_88" data-name="Path 88" d="M376.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(849.374 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_89" data-name="Path 89" d="M642.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.48-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(584.164 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_90" data-name="Path 90" d="M616.008,525.689q-.059,0-.119,0l-5.022-.375a1.617,1.617,0,0,1-1.448-1.268L600.7,475.788a.534.534,0,0,0-1.055.157l3.1,47.544a1.624,1.624,0,0,1-.421,1.224,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.177.519H597.32a1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.493-1.027c-9.617-25.391-6.134-75.143-6.107-75.643l.356-.359h0l19.155,3.335.041.04c6.545,4.847,9.377,61.606,8.336,72.4a1.943,1.943,0,0,1-.474,1.245,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.126.465Z" transform="translate(609.755 -19.546)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_17" data-name="Ellipse 17" cx="8.748" cy="8.82" rx="8.748" ry="8.82" transform="translate(1192.936 381.911)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_91" data-name="Path 91" d="M609.9,406.117a1.321,1.321,0,0,1-.265-.027l-22.468-2.907a1.889,1.889,0,0,1-1.335-2.014l2.15-11.968c-2.85-3.591-.157-12.866,1.584-15.21l-.673-1.837a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-.03-1.483,1.817,1.817,0,0,1,.846-1.074l9.118-4.884a1.509,1.509,0,0,1,2.115.987l1.788,4.879-.027.014c4.282,2.314,8.075,4.6,5.226,16.813l3.572,16.863a2.1,2.1,0,0,1-.594,1.418A1.445,1.445,0,0,1,609.9,406.117Z" transform="translate(611.851 34.067)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_92" data-name="Path 92" d="M553.047,416.918a3.759,3.759,0,0,1,.4.441l17.622-1.228,1.89-3.884,6.187,2.11-2.684,7.2a2.849,2.849,0,0,1-2.883,1.854l-20.039-1.532a3.723,3.723,0,0,1-4,1.438,3.78,3.78,0,0,1-.693-7.017,3.715,3.715,0,0,1,4.207.613Z" transform="translate(637 3.497)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_93" data-name="Path 93" d="M613.881,399.861a1.626,1.626,0,0,1,.052-1.345l3.634-7.236a4.444,4.444,0,0,1,5.621-2.857,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,2.834,5.667l-1.4,8.014a1.616,1.616,0,0,1-.758,1.108,1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.327.145l-7.681-2.578a1.606,1.606,0,0,1-.976-.918Z" transform="translate(593.868 18.911)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_18" data-name="Ellipse 18" cx="7.124" cy="7.182" rx="7.124" ry="7.182" transform="translate(1199.474 369.402)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_94" data-name="Path 94" d="M567.6,323.04a3.7,3.7,0,0,1-2.062-.174A2.47,2.47,0,0,1,564.312,321c-1.327-8.891,6.172-8.16,7.059-8.545a9.724,9.724,0,0,0,1.568-1.154,7.283,7.283,0,0,1,4.1-.909,11.724,11.724,0,0,1,4.979.614,7.481,7.481,0,0,1,3.309,3.075,15.6,15.6,0,0,1,1.641,4.285,10.778,10.778,0,0,1,.279,5.253,6.455,6.455,0,0,1-5.848,4.725,4.873,4.873,0,0,0-2.544-5.324,7.3,7.3,0,0,0-4.85-.582,21.183,21.183,0,0,1-3.217.4C569.724,322.886,568.451,322.949,567.6,323.04Z" transform="translate(625.804 68.782)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.573" height="139.408" viewBox="0 0 60.573 139.408">' +
                                '<g id="Group_10" data-name="Group 10" transform="translate(-364.839 -95.836)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_101" data-name="Path 101" d="M406.917,367.962a3.321,3.321,0,0,0-2.721,1.012,3.674,3.674,0,0,0-1.007,2.835l-11.1,5.118,5.294,3.581,9.727-5.409a3.618,3.618,0,0,0-.2-7.137Z" transform="translate(15.37 -246.348)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_26" data-name="Ellipse 26" cx="8.334" cy="8.733" rx="8.334" ry="8.733" transform="translate(369.187 97.763)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_102" data-name="Path 102" d="M110.666,433.556h4.16l1.979-16.814h-6.14Z" transform="translate(281.939 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_103" data-name="Path 103" d="M345.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H345.178Z" transform="translate(46.365 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_104" data-name="Path 104" d="M59.666,433.556h4.16L65.8,416.742h-6.14Z" transform="translate(315.633 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_105" data-name="Path 105" d="M294.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H294.178Z" transform="translate(80.06 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_106" data-name="Path 106" d="M293.522,546.53a1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.195l-.2-63.006,21.724-.877.16-.006,3.573,37.793.448,24.076a1.572,1.572,0,0,1-1.348,1.62l-5.273.65a1.479,1.479,0,0,1-1.171-.373,1.629,1.629,0,0,1-.533-1.154l-.939-25.578-4.558-15.924a.5.5,0,0,0-.558-.3.526.526,0,0,0-.411.5l-1.774,41.872a1.569,1.569,0,0,1-1.338,1.506l-6.089.785a1.477,1.477,0,0,1-1.2-.388Z" transform="translate(80.965 -319.492)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_107" data-name="Path 107" d="M277.416,405.1l-6.436-27.389c-2.005-8.534,2.576-17.127,10.212-19.155a12.475,12.475,0,0,1,10.556,1.972,15.823,15.823,0,0,1,6.338,10.948l4.2,32.424a1.653,1.653,0,0,1-.35,1.252,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.123.563l-21.879.6h-.04A1.552,1.552,0,0,1,277.416,405.1Z" transform="translate(95.698 -240.023)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_108" data-name="Path 108" d="M332.544,384.227l-16.317-8.305a5.871,5.871,0,0,1-.151-10.254,5.272,5.272,0,0,1,5.732.413l13.2,9.88,14.252-5.947a1.473,1.473,0,0,1,1.673.386l1.922,2.126a1.648,1.648,0,0,1,.408,1.285,1.612,1.612,0,0,1-.679,1.153l-12.759,8.772a7.134,7.134,0,0,1-7.283.491Z" transform="translate(67.532 -244.457)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_109" data-name="Path 109" d="M281.411,314.339a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.9-.411c-.266-.122-.542-.223-.807-.346-2.343-1.083-3.886-4.067-3.941-7.071a11.032,11.032,0,0,1,3.176-7.84,11.188,11.188,0,0,1,6.936-3.136c2.7-.246,5.735.573,7.242,3.26a3.269,3.269,0,0,1,.444,2.447,1.622,1.622,0,0,1-.369.678c-.673.716-1.344.178-2.03.13-.943-.065-1.79.848-2.095,1.918a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.075,3.339l0,.02a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.29,1.484,1.731,1.731,0,0,1-1.258.747,7.768,7.768,0,0,1-2.5,0,1.372,1.372,0,0,0-1.864.451,2.8,2.8,0,0,0-.236.814c-.332,1.812-.256,1.7-.588,3.516Z" transform="translate(92.887 -199.658)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_110" data-name="Path 110" d="M275.343,498.593a3.712,3.712,0,0,0,.582-2.963,3.55,3.55,0,0,0-1.794-2.37l1.563-12.6-5.663,2.894-.616,11.521a3.68,3.68,0,0,0,1.473,4.518,3.332,3.332,0,0,0,4.456-1Z" transform="translate(96.598 -318.986)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_111" data-name="Path 111" d="M274.229,423.209a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.318.078l-5.716.757a1.481,1.481,0,0,1-1.2-.388,1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.2l.045-41.822a5,5,0,0,1,4.126-4.987h0a4.675,4.675,0,0,1,4.011,1.343,5.182,5.182,0,0,1,1.469,4.135l-1.661,18.023.778,22.5a1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.016,1.567Z" transform="translate(98.362 -251.277)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: "Element",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-vector-square fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.573" height="139.408" viewBox="0 0 60.573 139.408">' +
                                '<g id="Group_10" data-name="Group 10" transform="translate(-364.839 -95.836)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_101" data-name="Path 101" d="M406.917,367.962a3.321,3.321,0,0,0-2.721,1.012,3.674,3.674,0,0,0-1.007,2.835l-11.1,5.118,5.294,3.581,9.727-5.409a3.618,3.618,0,0,0-.2-7.137Z" transform="translate(15.37 -246.348)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_26" data-name="Ellipse 26" cx="8.334" cy="8.733" rx="8.334" ry="8.733" transform="translate(369.187 97.763)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_102" data-name="Path 102" d="M110.666,433.556h4.16l1.979-16.814h-6.14Z" transform="translate(281.939 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_103" data-name="Path 103" d="M345.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H345.178Z" transform="translate(46.365 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_104" data-name="Path 104" d="M59.666,433.556h4.16L65.8,416.742h-6.14Z" transform="translate(315.633 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_105" data-name="Path 105" d="M294.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H294.178Z" transform="translate(80.06 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_106" data-name="Path 106" d="M293.522,546.53a1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.195l-.2-63.006,21.724-.877.16-.006,3.573,37.793.448,24.076a1.572,1.572,0,0,1-1.348,1.62l-5.273.65a1.479,1.479,0,0,1-1.171-.373,1.629,1.629,0,0,1-.533-1.154l-.939-25.578-4.558-15.924a.5.5,0,0,0-.558-.3.526.526,0,0,0-.411.5l-1.774,41.872a1.569,1.569,0,0,1-1.338,1.506l-6.089.785a1.477,1.477,0,0,1-1.2-.388Z" transform="translate(80.965 -319.492)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_107" data-name="Path 107" d="M277.416,405.1l-6.436-27.389c-2.005-8.534,2.576-17.127,10.212-19.155a12.475,12.475,0,0,1,10.556,1.972,15.823,15.823,0,0,1,6.338,10.948l4.2,32.424a1.653,1.653,0,0,1-.35,1.252,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.123.563l-21.879.6h-.04A1.552,1.552,0,0,1,277.416,405.1Z" transform="translate(95.698 -240.023)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_108" data-name="Path 108" d="M332.544,384.227l-16.317-8.305a5.871,5.871,0,0,1-.151-10.254,5.272,5.272,0,0,1,5.732.413l13.2,9.88,14.252-5.947a1.473,1.473,0,0,1,1.673.386l1.922,2.126a1.648,1.648,0,0,1,.408,1.285,1.612,1.612,0,0,1-.679,1.153l-12.759,8.772a7.134,7.134,0,0,1-7.283.491Z" transform="translate(67.532 -244.457)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_109" data-name="Path 109" d="M281.411,314.339a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.9-.411c-.266-.122-.542-.223-.807-.346-2.343-1.083-3.886-4.067-3.941-7.071a11.032,11.032,0,0,1,3.176-7.84,11.188,11.188,0,0,1,6.936-3.136c2.7-.246,5.735.573,7.242,3.26a3.269,3.269,0,0,1,.444,2.447,1.622,1.622,0,0,1-.369.678c-.673.716-1.344.178-2.03.13-.943-.065-1.79.848-2.095,1.918a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.075,3.339l0,.02a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.29,1.484,1.731,1.731,0,0,1-1.258.747,7.768,7.768,0,0,1-2.5,0,1.372,1.372,0,0,0-1.864.451,2.8,2.8,0,0,0-.236.814c-.332,1.812-.256,1.7-.588,3.516Z" transform="translate(92.887 -199.658)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_110" data-name="Path 110" d="M275.343,498.593a3.712,3.712,0,0,0,.582-2.963,3.55,3.55,0,0,0-1.794-2.37l1.563-12.6-5.663,2.894-.616,11.521a3.68,3.68,0,0,0,1.473,4.518,3.332,3.332,0,0,0,4.456-1Z" transform="translate(96.598 -318.986)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_111" data-name="Path 111" d="M274.229,423.209a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.318.078l-5.716.757a1.481,1.481,0,0,1-1.2-.388,1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.2l.045-41.822a5,5,0,0,1,4.126-4.987h0a4.675,4.675,0,0,1,4.011,1.343,5.182,5.182,0,0,1,1.469,4.135l-1.661,18.023.778,22.5a1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.016,1.567Z" transform="translate(98.362 -251.277)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                    ]
                    
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    text: "Background",
                    icon: '<i class="far fa-file-image fa-2x"></i>',
                }
            ],
          
        }
    },

    computed: {

    },

    methods: {
        backHome() {
             this.$router.push('/'); 
        },

        activated(id) {
            this.drawers.find(drawer => drawer.id === id)
            this.selected = id;
            this.active = !this.active;
        },

        startDrag: (evt, item) => {
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'
            evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
            evt.dataTransfer.setData('itemID', item.id)
        },

        onDrop (evt, list) {
            const itemID = evt.dataTransfer.getData('itemID')
            const drawer = this.drawers.find(drawer => drawer.id)
            const item = drawer.items.find(item => item.id == itemID)
            item.svg = list
        }
    },



}
</script>
```